# Signing Spring SAML SLO Response

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I've configured the included sample application and am able successfully perform both IdP and SP initiated SSO, and SP initiated SLO (using POST)

However, when sending an IdP initiated logout using Ping Federate, it fails saying that the logout response must be signed (however it succeeds in OpenAM). Looking through the SAML messages, the logout response isn't signed (it seems that Ping Federate is more strict than OpenAM), from what I understand, the response should always be signed.

4.4.3.4 Session Participant/Authority Issues  to Identity
Provider
...
It is RECOMMENDED that the HTTP exchanges in this step be made over either SSL 3.0 [SSL3] or
TLS 1.0 [RFC2246] to maintain confidentiality and message integrity. The 
message MUST be signed if the HTTP POST or Redirect binding is used. The HTTP Artifact binding,
if used, also provides for an alternate means of authenticating the response issuer when the artifact is
dereferenced.

The relevant part of my securityContext.xml is here..

```
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                            <constructor-arg value="/metadata/moocow.xml"/>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                   <property name="local" value="true"/>
                   <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                   <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
                   <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
                   <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
                   <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
                   <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
                   <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                   <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="true"/>
                   <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="true"/>
                   <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
```

However, I don't believe any of this applies to the signing of the response to the IdP.

Associated metadata file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="http___localhost_8080_spring-security-saml2-sample" entityID="http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample">
<md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>Stripped out for legibility
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SingleLogout"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SingleLogout"/>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SSO" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
</md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Am I missing something blindingly obvious here? Thanks.

John

Comment: Update... org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl.java line 242, sendLogoutResponse(...)'
`boolean signMessage = context.getPeerExtendedMetadata().isRequireLogoutResponseSigned();`  This value will always be false because sendLogoutResponse should only ever be called when   
`<property name="local" value="true"/>`
By SAML standard, I believe this should always be true but if I understand the intent, this should be changed to:  
`boolean signMessage = context.getLocalExtendedMetadata().isRequireLogoutResponseSigned();`  
I've tested with the above securityContext.xml.

Comment: John, I am running into the same issue here, did you find a solution?